# Is a sequence of all the same numbers monotonic?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm wondering based on the definition of monotonicity:

> A sequence where $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is monotonic.

So given that the sequence $a_n = 3$ is all the same numbers and is neither increasing or decreasing, is it monotonic?

Comment: Yes, a constant sequence is monotone.

Comment: Technically, this is called weakly monotone, meaning, that $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, a_n\leq a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a constant sequence (a number repeated indefinitely) is inceed monotonic: it is both monotonic non-decreasing, and monotonic non-increasing.

Hence, one can require that a sequence be **strictly** monotonic increasing or **strictly** monotonic decreasing. Under such a restriction, a constant sequence is neither strictly increasing nor strictly decreasing monotonically.

Comment: OP liked it too! =1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every constant sequence is monotone, in fact simultaneously monotone non-decreasing and monotone non-increasing.

Answer (score -1):

yes, because constant sequence is both increasing and decreasing sequence. so that it is monotonic.